# What does the process oobechk.exe do?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I see `oobechk.exe` running on a Windows 2008 Server. What is it? Is it safe?

Comment: You can find this information just searching for the process name on google.

Comment: Are you sure it's `oobeNchk.exe ` and not `oobechk.exe`?

Comment: "Just Google it" is really only valid for general reference questions. The top Google result for `oobechk.exe` isn't that great; I bet SU can do better. Although I'm not sure we want to encourage a flood of "is this process safe?" posts.

Comment: Evan, I'm editing to make the change suggested by @techie because `oobechk` has lots of results and `oobenchk` only has two, both pointing at this page. Feel free to roll back if it really is with the n, and sorry in advance.

Comment: Yea, I meant `oobechk.exe` good catch @Lord Torgamus

Comment: It should be running from the system32 folder, if not it is malware.

Comment: This should be the site where people can go to find out these answers.  I think it'd be great if eventually every process had a question, so that we were the definitive reference point.

Comment: Related Meta: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3392/file-purpose-and-usage-questions

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be part of the "manage your server" wizard, possibly other functions also.

> It's easy to see command-line parameters used to launch some applications, eg, the 'manage your server' wizard is started with:
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\oobechk.exe /LaunchMYS

[Referenced on this page](http://waynes-world-it.blogspot.com/2008_07_01_archive.html)

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I'm 99% sure that the "oobe" part refers to

[Out of Box Experience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-box_experience)

That is, this is some "check" that runs for the first time after you install the Windows Server operating system.

Thus: `oobechk.exe`